LINQ "SubmitChanges" is very slow
I was trying to insert more than 20,000 records data in database using LINQ.
Almost everything is fine until the line of SubmitChanges. It slows down my application. I tried commenting the submitchanges, the program is done in just about 1-3 minutes. But with SubmitChanges being executed, it took almost 2 hours to finish.
For reference:
The application will read an almost 1,000 text files. Each text file has a number of records that needs to be inserted in the database.
Additional:
The submitchanges is located outside the loop.
I tried Execute Command and using stored procedure, but to no avail.

You might want to look into frameworks that allow bulk inserts. The standard method of inserting 1 booking at a time, is likely the reason, however, there could be other problems. I would try using bulk inserts first.

It is not strange that submitChanges takes time, since that does all the actual work. I would probably consider if linq-to-sql is the right tool to use. AFAIK it has not been maintained much, and replaced with Entity framework in most situations. Or just use raw SQL, that should give you most control.

If your database is SQL Server you should use SqlBulkCopy

Thank you, the SqlBulkCopy solved my concern.
